# What is mime in the following code?

Tags: php, tags

can anyone tell me what is mime in the following line of code

```
echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
```

thank you

Comment: Take a look at how the `$check` array is created and populated!

Answer (score 1):

In your example mime is an array key. But MIME actualy is

```
The Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) type is a standardized way to 
indicate the nature and format of a document.
```

As it is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)